# Convergence of the improper integral $\int_{- \infty}^{1} x^n \, e^x \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'd like to know how to prove the convergence of the following integral:

$$
\int_{- \infty}^{1} x^n \, e^x \, dx
$$

I tried to solve it analytically, but it seems that the analytical solution doesn't exist ([Wolfram solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BExp%5Bx%5D*Power%5Bx%2Cn%5D%2Cx%5D)).
Maybe is it possible to prove the convergence without solving it?

Comment: If $n$ is an integer, an antiderivative exists (you can integrate by parts $n$ times).

Comment: Hello @ThomasBakx yes $n \geq 0$ is an integer. I'll try your way.

Comment: This can be expressed as a linear combination of the Gamma function and the incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: Hello @LaxmiNarayanBhandari these functions are new for me. Can you show me how please?

Comment: You'll find the required functions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Just substitute $x=-t$, separate the integral at $t=0$ and then use the definitions given in the Wikipedia page.

Comment: $n$ or $-n$ as you gave in WA input ?

Comment: Hello @ClaudeLeibovici I made a mistake

Comment: You are asking Wolfram for the indifinite integral. What happens if you specify the limits? I tried it myself, but I get "computation time exceeded" (but if I specify a positive integer for $n$, I get an integer multiple of $e$ as the result.)

Comment: Hello @TonyK I'm looking for a way to specify limits.

Comment: [This is one way](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x%5En+e%5Ex+for+x+%3D+-infinity+to+1).

Answer (score 0):

For non-negative $n$ and $x$, there is always a finite $x_n$ such that $$x>x_n\implies x-n\log x>\frac x2.$$

Hence the integral is bounded by the converging

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-x_n} e^{x/2}dx+\int_{-x_n}^{1} x^ne^{x}dx.$$

For negative $n$, the function has the behavior of $x^n$ around the origin and the rest converges.